# Serialization when extending a class whose GetObjectData method is not marked virtual

Tags: c#, serialization, binaryformatter, iserializable

I'm trying to extend a framework. One of the classes I am extending is  serialized. The base class' `GetObjectData()` method is not marked virtual so I can't override it.

Now if object gets serialized when it's referenced as a base class it's not polymorphic so only the base class' `GetObjectData` is called.

Is there any way around this without modifying the base class' `GetObjectData` to mark it as virtual?

[Edit] I extended the class and added an attribute that I want to serialize. Simple example of the problem below

```
[Serializable]
public class ParentClass : ISerializable 
{

    public float m_parent = 1.73f;

    public ParentClass() 
    { }

    public ParentClass(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        Debug.Log("Loading parent");
        m_parent = (float)info.GetValue("m_parent", typeof(float));
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        Debug.Log("Saving parent");
        info.AddValue("m_parent", m_parent, typeof(float));
    }
}


[Serializable]
public class ChildClass : ParentClass
{
    public int m_child = 73;

    public ChildClass()
    { }

    public ChildClass(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context)
    {
        Debug.Log("Loading child");
        m_child = (int)info.GetValue("m_child", typeof(int));
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        Debug.Log("Saving child");
        info.AddValue("m_child", m_child, typeof(int));
        base.GetObjectData(info, context);
    }
}

void Save()
{
    Debug.Log("Starting save");
    ParentClass aParent = new ChildClass() as ParentClass;
    using (Stream stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create))
    {
        BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        bFormatter.Serialize(stream, aParent);
    }
    Debug.Log("Save complete");
}

void Load()
{
    Debug.Log("Starting load");
    ChildClass aChild;
    using (Stream stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open))
    {
        BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        aChild = bFormatter.Deserialize(stream) as ChildClass;
    }
    Debug.Log("Load complete" + aChild.m_child);
}
```

Doing a save/load yields the following error:

`SerializationException: No element named m_child could be found.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Mark `ChildClass` explicitly as being `ISerializable`.
2. Declare a `GetObjectData` with the [`new`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx) modifier in the child class as Will suggests,

   **or**

   Implement the interface explicitly in the child class.

For instance:

```
[Serializable]
public class ChildClass : ParentClass, ISerializable
{
    public int m_child = 73;

    public ChildClass()
    { }

    public ChildClass(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Loading child");
        m_child = (int)info.GetValue("m_child", typeof(int));
    }

    public new void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Saving child");
        info.AddValue("m_child", m_child, typeof(int));
        base.GetObjectData(info, context);
    }
}
```

Since [`BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream, Object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5sbs8z9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is non-generic, the most derived interface implementation will be discovered and used.

For details of why this works, see the c# language specification [17.6.7 Interface re-implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/interfaces#1767-interface-re-implementation):

> A class that inherits an interface implementation is permitted to **re-implement** the interface by including it in the base class list.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly what you need `GetObjectData` for, you can use some custom methods to manipulate your object during serialization/deserialization:

```
[Serializable]
public MySerializableClass : MyUnforgivingBaseClass
{
    [OnSerializing]
    public void OnSerializing(StreamingContext context)
    {
         //You can modify the object before serialization here
    }

    [OnDeserializing]
    public void OnDeserializing(StreamingContext context)
    {
        //You can modify the object during deserialization here
    }
}
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializingattribute(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.onserializingattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: To add more detail to my problem,  I've added some attributes to the child class that I want serialized. Unless I'm missing something, `OnSerializing` doesn't provide access to the `SerializationInfo` object, so I can't add these new attributes to the serialization there.

Comment: You may need to implement `ISerializable` or `IXmlSerializable` but I'm still not sure that will solve your problem, especially if you are deserializing to the base class as well...

Comment: I don't think it will, since it would have to be polymorphic to work correctly...

Comment: Have you tried marking it as serializable and see if the attribute gets serialized? Can you update your post with the extended class and possibly the base class?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [new modifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx) to override the base class' implementation.

---

If it's *referenced* by the base class by the serializer, this won't help.  It would have to be referenced as the child type for the `new` override to work.

In this case, your only hopes would be to 1) replace serialization logic so you can control it, 2) use a proxy class for serialization purposes that is mapped back and forth to the framework class, 3) fork the framework to fix its limitations or 4) magic

Comment: I'm not sure `new` will fix where he described *"object gets serialized when it's **referenced as a base class** it's not polymorphic so the only the base class' GetObjectData is called."*.